# GPS fix with plastic lid closed

Tags: antenna, gps, system

I have a product where I'm using Adafruit [Product 746](https://www.adafruit.com/product/746) (Ultimate GPS Module - 66 channel w/10 Hz updates - PA1616S - MTK3339 Chipset). I'm using [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078Y2WNY6) external active GPS antenna "32db High Gain Cirocomm 5cm Active GPS Antenna Ceramic Antenna 25x25x2mm" which has a built in BT-580.

I get a fix when my enclosure is open (unlided). I lose the fix when I put the plastic (UV-resistant ASA plastic) lids on my enclosure within 15 seconds. Also in the lid, adjacent to the GPS antenna, is a Raspberry Pi 4B attached to a 5 inch touchscreen display.

I need advice figuring out what's wrong and how to fix it. I've tried switching out antennas and GPS modules to no avail. I've written a sketch to verify the GPS says it's using the external antenna and it is. When I say it's not getting a fix, I'm looking at the raw NMEA sentence traffic (so there's shouldn't be any software bug in play on my part).

I do have a coin cell battery installed in the GPS module as well.

What else can I try?

Comment: What type of plastic is the lid on the enclosure made out of? On a quick search it is possible to get some plastics which are deliberately designed to provide some shielding. E.g. [Electromagnetic Wave Shielding Property](https://www.plastics.toray/technical/torayca/tec_001.html)

Comment: Please include photos / diagrams to clarify the position of the various components in your box... please include a marker showing the up / sky direction.

Comment: @chestergillon UV-resistant ASA plastic

Comment: How is the GPS antenna mounted? Suspicions include: 1) did you use the correct thickness of plastic, the correct distance from the patch? These antennas are designed for a particular radome situation, read the datasheet to find out which. Sometimes they will be sold in several versions, tuned slightly differently to work correctly with various plastic radome situations. 2) did you meet its ground plane requirements?

Comment: No datasheet I can see. Worrying they're showing the VSWR of an active antenna. Perhaps the radome detuning is your problem - at minimum keep it 2 cm away from the lid, and give it a 100 mm diameter ground plane.

Answer (score 2):

While it's possible the plastic is causing some reduction in the efficiency of the GPS antenna, it's more likely that the GPS is experiencing radio frequency interference from emissions from the Raspberry Pi and/or touchscreen display.

Remove the Pi and screen from the lid and put them a few inches away, then put the all-plastic lid on. If this restores GPS function, you've confirmed its an EMI (electromagnetic interference) problem. It may be solved by shielding or relocating the rPi/screen, but it's hard to make recommendations without a picture of your configuration.

Comment: It’s quite possible that the lid is affecting the tuning of the antenna (rather than shielding it from RF).  If the antenna has a very narrow response then even a small shift in frequency can have a significant effect in performance.

Comment: @Frog Good point, and a nice writeup on that topic here:https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131218/material-that-degrade-gps-signal-reception

Answer (score 1):

Are you for real, placing a Raspberry Pi plus touchscreen **right above** the GPS antenna, and expect it to still work?

The thing you have left to try, is to place the antenna not below any metal objects that will interfere with the GPS signals.

Comment: Not right above it... more like adjacent to it. The antenna has a clear view of the sky through the lid.

Comment: `The antenna has a clear view of the sky through the lid` ... apparently not

Comment: With an active antenna I expect a high degree of noise immunity, should have a filter and a two stage amplifier built in...